# Applying a Custom Material Around a Cylinder Doesn't Work as Expected

Tags: python, materials

I'm really new to materials and Blender but I'm working on project where I want a plywood effect.

But the materials are being applied via code that detects normals and assigns a material for the face or ends.

So far this approach works excellent for cubes, but radius do not look continuous. Perhaps I don't need two separate materials and there is a better way to create the end grains so they wrap around cylinders?

.blend file here:
[image]

[image]
[image]

@RobinBetts, applying your updated material to other items as shown on the right (updated material) vs original material (left)
[image]

Comment: I think it might be easier to UV unwrap this one.. do you have a reason not to?

Comment: My only reason is that I don’t know how to do so using the Python API. My current method determines the normal direction of each face and just assigns a material to the face. But maybe I should experiment with an algorithm to texture map a UV unwrapped object. Thx!

Comment: Ahh, OK . You intend to automate. I missed that.. 'Python' tag added, even though you're not directly seeking help with that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make just one material with different texture mappings depending on the normal?

Comment: As @L0Lock suggests, is something like [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/OxRB0drL/) heading in the right direction?

Comment: , this is incredible and thank you for showing me this by example as I'm not good enough with materials to figure this out on my own. 

Can you expand on how the mix shader works? it seems the mask shader automatically applies the correct texture but the end grain texture is no a little off? maybe that is a simple adjustment?